# Routers are not learning routes when using RIP

Tags: routing, rip

I am trying to implement simple scenario of RIP using Packet Tracer, first of all here is the scenario.

[image]

and I have used the following commands to configure `RIPv2` in each router,

**R1:**

```
router rip
version 2
network 172.30.10.0
network 10.1.1.0
no auto-summary
```

**R2**

```
router rip
version 2
network 10.1.1.0
network 10.2.2.0
no auto-summary
```

**R3**

```
router rip
version 2
network 172.30.30.0
network 10.2.2.0
```

Now if i see the output of `show ip route` command on `R1`, it doesn't show any route to `172.30.0.0` subnet of `R3`,

```
     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.1.1.0 is directly connected, Serial0/1/0
     172.30.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.30.10.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

Similarly, here are the outputs of `R2` and `R3`

`R2`,

```
     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 2 subnets
C       10.1.1.0 is directly connected, Serial0/1/0
C       10.2.2.0 is directly connected, Serial0/1/1
     172.30.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
R       172.30.10.0 [120/1] via 10.1.1.1, 00:00:19, Serial0/1/0
```

`R2` only learned the path to `172.30.10.0` network on `R1` but not the path of the subnetworks in `R3`.

**R3**

```
     10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.2.2.0 is directly connected, Serial0/1/1
     172.30.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.30.30.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

I don't know what am I missing.
I read on other post that I was supposed to disable `auto-summary` in each router which I have already did, and I have also clear the routing table after that but it is not working either.

Comment: Can you ping both R1 and R3 from R2? Do you have any form of access lists configured on the interface? (Can be shown with `show ip interface <interface>`)

Comment: I haven't configured any access-list at all

Comment: You do need the `no auto-summary` in R3, but you also have an addressing problem on the serial link of R3. R2 thinks the network on that serial link is `/30`, but R3 thinks it is `/24`. You need to include the full configurations of those two routers so that we can track down the problem without guessing.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing **no auto-summary** in R3.  If that does not solve the problem maybe you need to issue the **'IP routing'** command in each router.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that as well, but the output is still the same.

Comment: may i is problem with serial links , try the Ethernet connections  instead

Answer (score 1):

Using no auto-summary in all the three routers have solved the issue.